# processwire multilanguage is not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am new to processwire (https://processwire.com) and trying to setup Multi Language for my website, i have follow all help and tutorials but i am unable to figure out how to get this working.

what i did let me explain it step by step.

1. I have installed all Language Modules , see the picture
2. i have added the language name arabic in Setup >> Languages, as i dont find any language translation file, so i did't process any file. see the picture.!
3. now when i Goto Edit Page, i can see two page names Default and Arabic see attachment
4. But when i goto Content i did't see any tab for arabic language where i can put data for arabic language, see picture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoIIY.png

i don't know what i am doing wrong or what missing, as i am new and can't figure out, can any one help me how to get this working and i hope this will also help new persons like me who are trying to use processwire.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change the field type from Textarea to TextareaLanguage. Just go to fields and click on the link of the "body" field. Then change the type to TextareaLanguage and hit save. (Same for title and headline)

Comment: it worked, thanks :)  but why admin title field for Arabic is not RTL? and how to make it ?